# How to control the connection pool size in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Link: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/

In Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4 onwards the SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE setting is deprecated.

1. What is default pool size?
2. Where can I control this value? The configuration api page doesn't mention this (https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

The pool size value can be configured with the new parameter that was added, `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS`. It takes all the parameters as [create_engine()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine), pool size is mentioned [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool_size). You can add this to your app config, like this:

`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {"pool_size": 20}`

or wherever you're defining the rest of the configurations, add this dict:

```
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    'pool_size': 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I am late to answer this question but just wanted to answer it anyway, You can modify the number of connections that SQlAlchemy can make to database in the following way:

```js
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'pool_size': 10,
    'max_overflow': 20,
    # Add any other engine-specific options here
}
```

Here , pool_size is the no. of connections that SQlAlchemy can create concurrently.
max_overflow is the no. of connections that SQLAlchemy can create once pool_size is exhausted.

Please note that If you do not want any limit for these 2(not recommended), you can use below:

'pool_size': 0,
'max_overflow': -1

Hope, this answer helps! If yes, then please consider upvoting :)